# As powerful as black holes are

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis

Recently, I've come across some "as+adj+as" patterns that don't fit into the famous "as+adj+as" pattern. Like, he is as old as me.

The new patters are as follow:

1. **As powerful as black holes are**, they will eventually evaporate.
2. **As scary as the event horizon is**, it keeps us safe from that drama.

I couldn't find much about this usage of "as+adj+as" pattern in English dictionaries.

What does this pattern mean? Does it mean "though" or it has some other function?

Comment: With this usage it is possible, and common, to leave out the first 'as' - "Scary as the even horizon is, it keeps us...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means *though* or *in spite of (some obvious fact).*

> Even though black holes are very powerful...
>
> Even though the event horizon is very scary...

Comment: But how did the poster know you were right? He's just taking your word. Surely this site deserves better.

Comment: It's not the easiest kind of grammatical usage to search for proof of!

Comment: Agreed. I tried on Google and gave up. But probably best redirected to ELL where the contributors are perhaps more used to dealing with such expressions.

Comment: Lexico has "even though" as one of its definitions of [as](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/as) (conjunction).